# Eclipse Extension Point for Updating the Classpath

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, eclipse-jdt

**Question**

Given a Classpath Container I've written as a plugin/extension, how do I add it to the classpath, automatically?

**Background**

Ok so I'm an experienced Java Developer but extremely new to writing Eclipse Plugins.  I've been googling, following tutorials and reading source code of other plugins for a couple days.  I know exactly what I want to do but not exactly how to do it.

Right now, in Eclipse, when I click a resource and choose "Run as JUnit test" as in:

---

[image: for some reason, my pics don't work anymore. I'll fix this soon...]

---

Behind the scenes, the m2eclipse plugin somehow generates a run configuration that contains the "Maven Dependencies" classpath container, like the following:

[image]

My best guess is that the "Maven Dependencies" classpath container is added through some extension point being used by the M2Eclipse plugin.  Similarly, I want to add my classpath container, automatically, whenever a user runs a JUnit test--so it shows up under "User Entries."  What extension point(s) can I use to make something like that happen?  I've been looking at *org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathContainerInitializer* but I'm not sure that's going to do what I need.

---

**Ideal Result**

Ideally, I'd like to write a plugin that takes every entry in the project's build path and adds it to the classpath of a run configuration (whenever a new launch configuration is created via: *Run As > JUnit test*).  This should be the default behavior of Eclipse but it's not!

My next-best solution would be to simply add my custom classpath container to the run configuration's build path, automatically.  At the end of the day, I just want one classpath for any java code our team runs/launches.  This shouldn't be so hard!

Any advise on how to achieve any of this would be appreciated!  Even basic pointers on where to look to understand how particular Extension Points are intended to be used (the basic JavaDocs APIs are terrible). Thanks,

- gMale

Comment: You could use Alt+Shift+F1 to open Plug-in Spy and get details about M2Eclipse plugin and then look into the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roostergx provides part of the answer (i.e., how to create the classpath container).  The second part, as you admit, is how to add it automatically.

I would recommend using an extension point called org.eclipse.ui.startup.  This allows you to contribute code that runs (pretty much) as early as possible when Eclipse starts up.  On every startup, you can iterate through all projects and see if any existing projects require the classpath container that you created.

Comment: thanks. This is more along the lines of what I'm looking for.  There must be some other extension point for contributing code that runs right before a Run Configuration is executed. At the end of the day, all I want is a classpath container that 1) adds all the jars in the Lib directory to the build path 2) is included by default in all run configurations. This should be built into Eclipse by default!

Comment: No, there is no extension point for doing what you are suggesting.  The closest thing to do would be to create your own launch configuration.  It can be a direct subclass/copy of the JUnit launch, but it would also add your extra libraries.

Comment: I finally solved my root problem a couple weeks ago by putting my jars under path/to/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/libs. This worked perfectly since jars in that directory are automatically included by the *Web Apps Libraries* classpath container in all run configurations. I'll accept this since your answer is closest to solving my question above (that is, I think it would actually work).

Answer (score 0):

The article at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-classpath/index.html provides an exellent description and source for a plugin that defines a project specific classpath container that includes all the jar files in a specified directory.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I haven't looked at this problem in a while... Creating the container is doable... but not having to add it **by hand** to a run configuration (i.e., automatically included whenever someone clicks *Run As > JUnit test*) is the hard part. The *Maven Dependencies* container works that way... so it must be possible, right?